# Position of div changing on different screen resolutions

Tags: html, css

When I do the following, the images, used as links, contained in the div change position if I open up on a screen with a higher resolution. How can I solve this?

HTML:

```
    <div class="image-links">
   <ul>
     <li>
<a href="">
   <img src="images/rooms.png" alt="the rooms" width="inherit">
 </a>
</li>
<li>
 <a href="">
    <img src="images/dive-site.png" alt="dive site" width="inherit">
  </a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="">
     <img src="images/food.png" alt="food" width="inherit">
   </a>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-links{
width: 300px;
float: right;
position: absolute;
right: 3em;
top: 32.5em;
font-size: 20px;
margin: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Don't use static sizes on images or fonts. Make them relative by setting widths/heights to percentages. Also, understand that you really can't make a page that will look exactly the same in all resolutions - - that should not be your goal. Develop mobile-first. Also, you are combining float and absolute positioning, which are contradictory.

Comment: I tried changing all of the values to percentages, unfortunately the images still end up way off when on a higher resolution screen.

Comment: You'll have to explain/show us what "way off" means in your opinion.